# Scalable Kinetic.JS vector map

Tags: javascript, html, flash, svg, kineticjs

I have an flash application with **colossal** interactive scalable vector worldmap seperated by extra large amount of selectable layers (such as population map, resource map, etc) which i need to port into html5 Kinetic.JS. So, all layer graphic goes in swf/swc/fla.
What is the perfomance best practices for such application here in htmlt5? Should i convert all graphics to svg (is it possible for vector swf?) and simple scale it on runtime, or would it be better to rasterize it as some mipmap (premade scaled versions of graphic) and draw premaded images instead of scaling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KineticJS is canvas based and canvas can use .SVG images for scaling with less pixelizing.

**Better Visual Results**

For best visual results, you should stick with Kinetic.Image using .SVG image source if possible.

**Better Performance**

The most recent release of Kinetic (5.1.0) has added a Kinetic.FastLayer which increases drawing performance by eliminating the overhead of the eventing system.

For better performance you can use FastLayers+scaling for all map+overlay layers except the user interactivity layer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I sure it is my bad formalization of problem, but i was asking about perfomance optimization in this kind of situation. So, i know about kinetic.js svg support but scaling hight amount of vector map layers would cause colossal lag, i think. So i was asking about any way to optimize this problem (cached mipmap, cached layers or pure svg scaling).

Comment: I see now.  I have reworked my answer to focus on better visual and performance results.  Cheers!